# Index out of range, but list has elements in it?

Tags: python, list, indexing

So I've been looking through this site to try to resolve my issue, but I don't think anyone has my specific problem?
What I'm trying to do is iterate through and create permutations of the list with repeats. Similar to if I wanted all the possible outcomes of rolling a 4 sided dice 3 times. I don't know if my code is actually going to work for this purpose, but the problem at hand is this:

I have this code:

```
ops = ["add", "sub", "mul", "div"]    
def opsy():
    opslist=["cat", "dog", "cow"]
    for w in ops:
        opslist[0] = w
        for x in ops:
            opslist[1] = x
            for y in ops:
                opslist[2] = y
                opsarray.append(opslist)
```

And I get this error:

```
IndexError: 'list assignment index out of range'
```

Which I understand should be because `opslist` was defined as an empty list, so I changed that (as seen in the above code) and I still get the error? 
Also I don't think "`append`" isn't what I want, I need to be able to change a specific index and not just add an item. I also don't want to use modules (itertools), I would really like to program this myself.
Thanks much.

EDIT:
I don't know why I have an error then? But anyway martineau's comment with `opsarray = [[w, x, y] for y in ops for x in ops for w in ops]` worked for what I wanted to do. So yes. Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to build combinations, use `itertools.product()` instead: `opsarray = itertools.product(ops, repeat=3)`. Even if you didn't get out of range errors, you still are only adding the *same list* to `opsarray`, over and over again, so you'll end up with the same result repeat 4 ** 3 = 64 times.

Comment: And I cannot reproduce your exception with this code.

Comment: I can't either. you need to add `opsarray = []` to append to it other than that this code runs fine.

Comment: I don't get an `IndexError` from the code shown either. However afterward `oparray` is full of only `[['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ...]`. You can fix that by changing the `opsarray.append(opslist)` to `opsarray.append(opslist[:])` so that it will append a _copy_ of the contents of the list at that point into `opsarray` rather than a reference to it -- which is why its final values shows up 64 times at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

Your code does *not* raise an exception. You do have a different problem however: you are adding the same list (`opslist`) to `opsarray` 64 times, while constantly altering that list. In the end you have 64 references to the same list:

```
>>> opsarray
[['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div'], ['div', 'div', 'div']]
>>> id(opsarray[0]) == id(opsarray[1])
True
```

You want to create new lists:

```
ops = ["add", "sub", "mul", "div"]    
def opsy():
    for w in ops:
        for x in ops:
            for y in ops:
                opsarray.append([w, x, y])
```

or better still, use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
opsarray = list(product(ops, repeat=3))
```

which results in:

```
[('add', 'add', 'add'), ('add', 'add', 'sub'), ('add', 'add', 'mul'), ('add', 'add', 'div'), ('add', 'sub', 'add'), ('add', 'sub', 'sub'), ('add', 'sub', 'mul'), ('add', 'sub', 'div'), ('add', 'mul', 'add'), ('add', 'mul', 'sub'), ('add', 'mul', 'mul'), ('add', 'mul', 'div'), ('add', 'div', 'add'), ('add', 'div', 'sub'), ('add', 'div', 'mul'), ('add', 'div', 'div'), ('sub', 'add', 'add'), ('sub', 'add', 'sub'), ('sub', 'add', 'mul'), ('sub', 'add', 'div'), ('sub', 'sub', 'add'), ('sub', 'sub', 'sub'), ('sub', 'sub', 'mul'), ('sub', 'sub', 'div'), ('sub', 'mul', 'add'), ('sub', 'mul', 'sub'), ('sub', 'mul', 'mul'), ('sub', 'mul', 'div'), ('sub', 'div', 'add'), ('sub', 'div', 'sub'), ('sub', 'div', 'mul'), ('sub', 'div', 'div'), ('mul', 'add', 'add'), ('mul', 'add', 'sub'), ('mul', 'add', 'mul'), ('mul', 'add', 'div'), ('mul', 'sub', 'add'), ('mul', 'sub', 'sub'), ('mul', 'sub', 'mul'), ('mul', 'sub', 'div'), ('mul', 'mul', 'add'), ('mul', 'mul', 'sub'), ('mul', 'mul', 'mul'), ('mul', 'mul', 'div'), ('mul', 'div', 'add'), ('mul', 'div', 'sub'), ('mul', 'div', 'mul'), ('mul', 'div', 'div'), ('div', 'add', 'add'), ('div', 'add', 'sub'), ('div', 'add', 'mul'), ('div', 'add', 'div'), ('div', 'sub', 'add'), ('div', 'sub', 'sub'), ('div', 'sub', 'mul'), ('div', 'sub', 'div'), ('div', 'mul', 'add'), ('div', 'mul', 'sub'), ('div', 'mul', 'mul'), ('div', 'mul', 'div'), ('div', 'div', 'add'), ('div', 'div', 'sub'), ('div', 'div', 'mul'), ('div', 'div', 'div')]
```

Comment: `opsarray = [[w, x, y] for y in ops for x in ops for w in ops]` is another, very succinct, possibility.

Comment: Indeed, but with `itertools.product()` available there really is no need.